# Странное поведение @media CSS

Tags: html, css

Имеется код:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
      #s-f-submit {
        position: fixed;
    }
}
```

При ширине экрана в 1024 пикселей или меньше, меняем позишин блока.

Но при этом, когда я уменьшаю условие максимальной длины до 991px, то есть:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
      #s-f-submit {
        position: fixed;
    }
}
```

Правило срабатывает только когда ширина экрана МЕНЬШЕ 991 пикселей, то есть максимум на 990. Хотя в первом правиле с 1024, позиция fixed приписывается на ширине 1024 включительно.

Что это такое, и чем это вызвано? п.с подключен бутстрап 5.

Comment: я не знаток бутстрапа но там вроде свои медиа прописаны а точно твой медиа применяется или может ихний потому как такое не возможно ...  (max-width: Хpx)  если ширина окна браузера составляет Х пикселей или меньше

Comment: @Armen не поверите но вот так вот получается, сам не могу понять почему. Пробовал с разных браузеров